# Question marked incorrectly as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I posted a question about video's for HTML5 and it ended up being marked as a duplicate, yet the question linked was in no way helpful. It simply told me something I already knew and it's answer was what I already had...

One problem being if it isn't a very popular question... good luck trying to get it reopened. There has to be someway to prevent people from marking your question as a duplicate while they have not read either your question or the duplicated answer.

Here is the question: [Cross-browser HTML5 video compatibility not working with multiple video formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917270/cross-browser-html5-video-compatibility-not-working-with-multiple-video-formats)

Comment: Yes, there is a solution to preventing your question from being incorrectly marked as a duplicate; explain the question clearly enough that it's obvious why the answer to the other question does not solve your problem.  You can do this though edits as well as comments if you didn't get it right the first time.

Comment: Might have been a case of they read the title and assumed it was a dupe. People make mistakes. Looking at it, you use pretty much the same code from the answer of the dupe target, yet it doesn't work. So I can see how it's not a dupe. Unfortunately, I can't vote to reopen. But bringing it up on Meta, I'm sure if enough people agree it's not a dupe, it'll get reopened. As @Servy said, try to explain clearly how it's not a dupe. Edit the question to make it more clear. Note: Do not put a huge "EDIT:" in your post, but maybe link to it and say you read it but are already using that solution.

Comment: @Kendra thanks! yeah I decided to post a link, maybe it will get reopened, but I did actually solve the issue. So if it does get reopened I will definitely post the answer.

Comment: @Adjit I was actually going to suggest that solution myself. I'm glad you solved it. :) Hopefully it'll get reopened soon for you.

Comment: My god even this question has been marked as a duplicate! The answer is that the guy who marks everything as duplicate has an itchy trigger finger. Over the years using stackoverflow I've come to realise that uniquely on stackoverflow, the term 'duplicate' actually means "fundamentally different in every way, shape and form to it's very core".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best way to prevent your posts from being marked as duplicates is to do a thorough search of your topic beforehand, and if you find posts that seem related, link to them in your question and explain why your question is different or why the answers to those questions didn't help you.

Comment: now what if the post which is marked as a duplicate is really a question that would precede mine? If you look at both questions my question is essentially an issue with the answer from the duplicate question. I don't necessarily think that warrants a link between the 2 questions

Comment: @Adjit I disagree that a link is unwarranted. I'm not well versed in HTML or web development, and I can completely see why this question was marked as a duplicate. You're asking about videos not playing in Chrome with code written in HTML5. You know they're not duplicates because of how well you know the subject, but I would not be able to distinguish between them because of how many similarities there are. A simple link and one line note about why they're different would be enough for me to not mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Adjit I know it may seem silly, but it's really a defensive measure against duplicate flags that I think is worth taking. Also, providing more context and background to your question may help potential answerers (that understand your topic) give you better answers.

Comment: Thanks @SLawson. Yeah, you are right... it really isn't too hard to  post the link which I did now, but even so I probably would not have thought to link the questions even if I had seen it prior.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: It's not always easy to predict the kinds of mistakes people with less knowledge than oneself are likely to make. Smart people are creative, but often still wrong; therefore smart people can be creatively wrong.

Comment: @MichaelScheper I fully agree with you, but I'm not sure your comment relates to this answer. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @skrrgwasme: It was in response to this: 'You know they're not duplicates because of how well you know the subject, but I would not be able to distinguish between them because of how many similarities there are.' It's advice worth considering, but my point is that we can't rely on it every time. I found this question when searching for what to do about a question that's been marked as a dupe for years. Despite four or five comments pointing out how it really is a different question, the moderators either still don't understand why, or haven't bothered looking into it.

Comment: this is unhelpful, the question is about what to do when a question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate, not how to prevent that happening

Comment: This answer not answers the question asked

Comment: This is the dumbest answer ever. He said INCORRECTLY marked as duplicate so you can do research until you're blue in the face and it won't help anything.