# I question the duplicate system as it is currently implemented

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I see posts like these:

[Question marked incorrectly as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271633/question-marked-incorrectly-as-duplicate?rq=1)

[Can't I answer my question, which is marked as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371111/cant-i-answer-my-question-which-is-marked-as-duplicate)

Other than the obvious (we don't like duplicates), I have to ask myself what are we really trying to solve? Are we trying to make the user experience better for the first time user? For the seasoned user? For the moderators?  I question that the duplicate system does so.

Personally I'm frustrated with the system but perhaps I have two ideas and I'll be brave enough to be slaughtered by the negative train...

- Make the duplicate tag something that comes into effect <strike>24 hours</strike> 30 minutes
  after the mark. This gives the OP a chance to evolve the question in
  a way that has dialog and answer it themselves.
- <strike>Or, get rid of the duplicate system and use the tag "may have an
  answer here..." with a link. If the other answer really does solve
  the OP question then it will die on the vine.</strike>

After dialog I agree that there is value with the duplicate system.

I've come to the conclusion that my frustrations with the system are with perception on my part. I perceived the duplicate system to be extra work that might be avoided if the original poster had a chance to refine their post before it was marked as duplicate and any further dialog curtailed (Again this is part of the perception. This is how it looked to me from the outside looking in. I could care less what YOU believe the perception should be). Now over time my perception has changed.

I'm left with the following:

Do as much work ahead of time before asking the question. Forget about asking a casual question. Yes I understand the reasoning. I understand why you want to discourage these kinds of question. If you comment and misunderstand this point then by god the horse will never die.

If you by chance don't understand and perceive the world like those who may mark your post as a duplicate and despite your best efforts they cling to the idea that you've  asked the SAME damn question... well walk away. Come back later and open a new question.  I don't see the point of editing the question again. Ok so that last part was a bit tongue in cheek. From this point on I'll edit the damn thing again and hope the SO moderators and I will reach an understanding.

Thanks everyone for your time. I understand that I've not expressed my concerns well, but again that's sort of my point.

/cheers

Comment: `If the other answer really does solve the OP question then it will die on the vine.` lol, no. It never does. It's much more lucrative reputation-wise to answer the same question over and over.

Comment: @Pekka ok. I concede that point. How about delaying the enforcement of the duplicate?

Comment: @D-Klotz: Delaying it will only open up the extremely simple duplicates to more and more duplicate answers. [See also this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357183/dupe-hammer-remove-grace-period-for-posting-an-answer).

Comment: Why do we need a delay? The current "workflow" is [open question] -> [get shown it's a dupe] -> [edit to clarify it isn't] -> [if edit is clear enough, reopen]. What's the benefit of [open question] -> [get pointed to dupe] -> [edit to correct] -> [have people validate if it is better or not, then close or not]. I am confused how one is better than the other, except that it leaves the question open for longer.

Comment: Why delay the enforcement? Either something's a duplicate or it's not. Delaying enforcement would just encourage help vampires and rep hounds who would be able to get reputation/answers/etc. with very little effort on their part.

Comment: @EjoshuaS I now agree with you. What you've stated is something I hadn't concerned myself with. I was looking at from the perspective of a simple user trying to evolve their question. Perhaps it is a duplicate. Perhaps after a bit of evolution, it isn't. I at first viewed the duplicate coming in within the first 45 seconds a needless increase in everyone's work. I've now come to understand why. I don't necessarily like it, but I see why.

Comment: You know what would be useful would be if there was a way for someone to clarify which answer is the duplicate. In my case the first duplicate has 46 answers. It would be useful if either I or someone else could clarify exactly which one within the duplicate is the answer.

Comment: [*I'm finding that the duplicate tag is the "easy" button for those with the power.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371111/cant-i-answer-my-question-which-is-marked-as-duplicate#comment610647_371111) let me say on that particular question it wasn't easy at all. I had to understand the two context of questions, verify if they match enough, then verify if the answer is any good and still applicable to the context of the OP. And that goes for more duplicate questions. Enough times that I might have written an rough outline of an answer then that I find an appropriate dupe.

Comment: @rene then I do apologize Rene.

Comment: @D-Klotz no need to apologize. There are also plenty of questions (null reference exceptions for example) that need no re-search effort from me, those are indeed easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> what are we really trying to solve?

We're trying to avoid repeating the same answers to the same questions over and over again.  The main reason is that it results in higher quality answers to said questions.  When people are constantly answering the same questions over and over again they get answered lazily; they get quick an easy answers that are just enough to satisfy one person, rather than a good canonical answers likely to be useful to anyone with the same problem.

By directing all of the duplicate questions to one place, it becomes worthwhile to take the time to write a really good answer.  The additional effort spend on good editing, making the answer as clear as possible, expanding on additional points likely to be relevant to readers, etc. is able to be amortized across many more people helped.  People take the time to really make a good canonical answer *shine*.  For repeated answer to a common duplicate, they don't.

Experts (and, well, most everyone) tends to get tired of answering common duplicates after a while.  So what you end up with is users who are much less knowledgeable, and much less experienced, trying to write answers to the common duplicates, and they're just not *capable* of writing good answers.  They tend to have errors, be less clear, etc.

Additionally, when a given problem has multiple viable solutions, it encourages them all to be in one place.  Rather than having 10 duplicate questions, each with 10 different answers, you have *one* question, with ten different answers, allowing the answers to be easily compared by others with the problem.   It not only means that those looking for answers don't need to look at 10 different questions to find the different solutions, but they actually get ordered properly by votes, so it becomes much easier to see which solutions the community likes most and which it doesn't.  It also just allows said people to even  *realize* that there are lots of different solutions/answers, rather than them just coming across the first version that they find and thinking that the one answer it has is the only viable solution.

> Are we trying to make the user experience better for the first time user?

Yes, by giving them better answers, as described above.

> For the seasoned user?

Yes, by removing the need for them to repeat the answers to questions.

> For the moderators?

Not really.  It's more work than just not having it.

> I question that the duplicate system does so.

How so?  Who is it bad for, and why?

> Make the duplicate tag something that comes into effect 24 hours after the mark. This gives the OP a chance to evolve the question in a way that has dialog and answer it themselves.

Their questions shouldn't be *evolving*.  If they have a new question, they can ask a new question.  If their question was unclear, or otherwise misunderstood by readers, they can edit the question to clarify it.  If the duplicate no longer applies, it can be reopened.

This would primarily serve to just encourage people to constantly re-post the same (low quality) answers to duplicate questions, which we explicitly don't want.

> Or, get rid of the duplicate system and use the tag "may have an answer here..." with a link. If the other answer really does solve the OP question then it will die on the vine.

This has the same problem as above, only more pronounced.  It fails to accomplish the goals of duplicates, namely keeping all of the answers in one place.  If someone feels that they can provide a better answer than any of the existing answers on the canonical then *they can post a new answer on the canonical*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I think what you've written is partially realized. Again, articulation and understanding.... Ok. I agree in principal what the dup system tries to solve.  Problems as a casual user of SO: 1) duplicate marking happens to quickly. 2) SO is already littered with duplicates. 3) I don't agree that walls of answers are useful. We will simply have to agree to disagree

Comment: @D-Klotz How is getting a quality answer to your question quickly a problem?  The fact that there are a lot of duplicates isn't a reason to not handle duplicates effectively.  The fact that there are a lot of them just makes the feature all the more important.  We wouldn't need them if there weren't a lot of them.  If you don't think longer answers are useful, and prefer more concise answers, then vote accordingly, or add additional, more concise, answers where appropriate.

Comment: Again we are not on the same page. Most likely it is me. Your first sentence. I agree. Don't know why you stated it. Second. I agree. Not my point. What I am trying to say, as our dialog illustrates is that by now this misunderstanding between you and I may have resulted in this post being marked as duplicate. Then I have to edit it, hope that you will take the time to review it and open it again. I hope you enjoy the extra work. I wouldn't. I am simply asking (now) that we delay the enforcement of the duplicate tag. Its taken us this long and I'm still not certain that we see eye to eye.

Comment: @D-Klotz The burden is on someone asking a question to ask a clear question.  If they ask a question that is interpreted incorrectly by the people reading it, it will cause problems.  That's unavoidable.  That's why it's important to ask a clear question to begin with, and to clarify an unclear question as effectively and as quickly as possible.  You can't just not do either of those things and try to avoid the consequences of having an unclear question (without actually clarifying the question).  All your change would do is change what those problems are, specifically, making them worse.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. I'm going to try one more time. I am a casual user of SO. 1) I search through SO. I find IMHO that the questions there do not answer my question. 2) I ask my question 3) Perhaps my skills at articulating my question are poor. 4) Before I get a chance to evolve the question based on comments into something that I originally intended and something you can actually understand - it is marked as duplicate. 5) yes I can edit. Yes I could make another question. 6) Those seem like extra work for you and me. 7) If we delayed negative and dup tags then perhaps we both walk away happy.

Comment: @D-Klotz *"I search through SO. I find IMHO that the questions there do not answer my question."*, if this is already done and you've *genuinely attempted the solutions provided*, then in the question you end up posting you *need to explain to us **why that post doesn't answer your question***. You should be defending your question before it's even posted.

Comment: @D-Klotz You have all the time in the world before you post to formulate your question.  If your question isn't a duplicate, then it's on you to ensure we *know* that.  Show your research!  Point at the duplicate, and tell us *why* it doesn't solve your problem.  If you didn't find that one in your research, read it over!  Does it solve your problem?  Great!  Everybody's happy!  If it doesn't solve it, then clarify your question as to why it doesn't.  Is it extra work?  Sure.  But it's valuable work; it helps more people find the same answers, so everybody gets help.

Comment: @D-Klotz How are you going to more effectively improve the question to articulate what you actually mean if the question is not closed?  How is the question being closed *more* work for you?  You still need to improve the question such that it actually is understood.  Preventing it from being closed only serves to potentially allow people to post answers to an unclear question, or try to repeat the answers.  It would also often result in the author delaying clarifying the question.  If the question isn't closed, they're much less likely to realize they need to clarify it, so they won't.

Comment: @D-Klotz how is your proposed 24 hour delay better though? "I show you it's a dupe" -> "you edit to clarify it isn't" -> "me or someone has to go back and check if it's STILL a dupe". There is no time saved at all. You just kept the question opened while we work, whereas the current system keeps it closed...  (you editing and someone reviewing is the same in both scenarios... there is literally no work saved)

Comment: Ok please take a step back for a moment. By trade I'm a software engineer but at one point in the distant past I worked with customers. A field engineer. What that taught me is that putting yourself in the shoes of the user is what really matters. I'm a casual user of SO. When you mark something as duplicate. I'm done. I get annoyed, put a bit of effort into it and then walk way with the idea that realistically there is little that I can do.  You've all posted great details that I either didn't know or really don't want to take the time to do. Its busy work.

Comment: @D-Klotz Odd that in response to getting a great answer to your question your reaction is to be annoyed and walk away, instead of using that great answer to solve your problem.  Using the answer to solve your problem doesn't really seem like "busy work" for me.  If you think that, then you aren't going to get a lot of effective use out of the site, that's true.  I don't think that's a reason to remove a valuable feature though.

Comment: @D-Klotz If you can't put in the effort to clarify your question, why should anyone put in the effort to help you clarify it?  For that matter, why should anyone even engage with you?  You want help, right?  That means you need to invest into your question.  If you can't even do that, there's no reason for anyone to invest in reopening it, either.

Comment: @Servy what are you talking about? "Odd that in response to getting a great answer to your question your reaction is to be annoyed". It is a generalization. I'm saying that in general when I see a duplicate tag on my own work that I get annoyed. It doesn't mean that that's all that happens or how it ends.

Comment: @D-Klotz And why, in general, are you annoyed by getting a great answer to your question?  Even if that's not all that happens, or how it ends, why in the world would that annoy you?

Comment: @fbueckert It isn't that I do not wish to put in the effort. Within this dialog, part of the issue seems to be the idea that a question should have everything in it to start with. I unfortunately find that difficult to do every time. I was looking for a way to allow people like me to evolve the question before it receives the negative train and the duplicate tag. But we are just beating this horse to death. I don't see anything we can agree on.

Comment: @Servy.  User see's duplicate tag on their post they just made. About 45 seconds have transpired between when the OP asked the question and the duplicate tag. That is when I get annoyed. Does that help clarify what I'm trying to say?

Comment: @D-Klotz but what's your concern with the duplicate marking itself? You argue for it to change, saying the current system is "a lot of work". However, your proposed change doesn't impact the amount of work done. It feels like you have an issue with duplication, PERIOD. Which you can. But the arguments you give don't align with your proposed changes.

Comment: @Patrice This dialog (how many comments) in a way proves to me what I've been attempting to say. I made a post. You made a comment. Others have. My question and understandings have evolved. I now need to go back and edit my OP. Is it already marked as dup? Most likely. I now understand the concerns about quick answers that have already been made and trying to avoid them. I don't have an easy answer based on what I've learned. I can just tell you at this point it is frustrating as a casual user of SO.

Comment: @D-Klotz I think what you're running into is the high quality standard of SE.  We want content to be the absolute best it can be.  You see that as getting it right the first time, we see it as investing enough of yourself into your question to ensure we understand it well enough to be able to help you.  When you put in effort, you *get* effort back.  People work with you to help you figure out what's happening, and how to fix it.  This expectation of just dumping a question and getting help doesn't fly here.  We get frustrated by users who don't care, and just want help, quality be damned.

Comment: @D-Klotz No, that doesn't clarify anything at all.   You made a post, within 45 seconds you got a high quality answer that answers your question.  Why in the world would you be annoyed.  Use the answer, solve the problem, feel great.

Comment: @D-Klotz What do you think we, as readers, have misunderstood about your question?  What do you want to edit it to say differently?  Had you been directed to another question explaining the information that has already been explained to you, why would it be any more problematic than having someone post an answer here, explaining the same thing?  How would that change how you'd clarify your question?

Comment: @D-Klotz ok. Then you edit, which brings your question to the reopen queue. The reopen queue, if your edit was correct, will have your question be reopened. Your proposed changes only stops the marking for 24 hours, which honestly deals only with the "frustration" part. But if there is no dupe marking for 24 hours AND the question stays opened during that time, then the OPs have no incentives to correct it. More often than not, what'll happen is "OP won't do anything. Question gets closed. OP panics and finally edits".

Comment: That added 24 hours then just has 2 consequences: 1) delayed frustration 2) question being opened an extra day might attract more answers.

Comment: @Servy No. Sometimes you get a high quality answer, sometimes you do not. It isn't that the answer is poor, it is that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @D-Klotz Sure, on rare occasions, your question was unclear and so you didn't get a good answer.  But most of the time that doesn't happen, and you just get the answer to your question.  If the question was misunderstood, the situation is effectively the same as someone misunderstanding the question and just posting a wrong answer, namely it is on you to improve the question and clarify what you're actually asking.  At some point if people are going to ask unclear questions that aren't going to be understood *it will cause frustration*.  That's why we close questions that aren't clear.

Comment: You really do have a blue sky view of how it works. Regardless, thanks for the time you've taken to reply.

Comment: @D-Klotz Given that you think that duplicates are universally wrong, and that we should remove the feature entirely as a result, almost everything is an optimistic viewpoint in comparison.

Comment: @Servy I can see why you'd make that statement given how this has played out, But how you've worded it is to strong a statement. I'd like to see it work, it just doesn't seem to given its current implementation for at least one casual SO user.

Comment: @D-Klotz Given that you've proposed removing the feature in entirety, I wouldn't say you're looking to see it work.  If you were, you wouldn't propose the whole thing go away.  As for the system failing you, you asked a question, one that was woefully under researched.  The answer to your question is easily found with even the most trivial of searches, and there is *lots* of quality resources available on the topic.  But rather than doing your research, you just asked on SO instead, and were directed to questions that answer it.

Comment: You got the answer to your question without having to do your research, and other people didn't have to re-type the same answer to this question that's asked multiple times every day.  Everyone benefited by the existence of the duplicate question feature.  That you're upset because you think it's too burdensome on you to simply have to read the answer to your own question is...rather unreasonable.

Comment: @Servy removing the feature was one suggestion. I'd like to think this dialog has modified my outlook. You are making some assumptions on what I researched. Is that fair? In the java swing world one of the tough things for new developer to realize is that pushing updates to components is something that must be done on the event queue thread. It isn't an obvious thing for the newbie. I've seen seasoned developers screw it up. I was looking for something similar in C# and spent a while searching. I had hoped I worded it correctly. I didn't. It was duped. Don't presume to know what I did in prep

Comment: @D-Klotz There is lots of readily available information out there on the topic.  Virtually any amount of research is going to result in you finding your answer.  And given that the question itself uses the relevant terms, you can't claim that you didn't know enough of the terminology to look for it.  So, while I can't comment on how much research you did, I can say that any reasonable amount of research would result in you finding the answer.  But again, the existence of the feature still helped you.  You were given the answer to your question, the duplicates.

Comment: @Servy it gave me answers to a different question.... is the horse dead yet?

Comment: @D-Klotz It gave you answers to questions with trivial differences that aren't relevant to its answer, and as a result gave you the answer to your question, solving your problem.  This has apparently upset you because you aren't interested in having your solution answered, it seems.

Comment: So you decide if my question is answered?

Comment: @D-Klotz You're free to explain how the duplicates fail to answer your question, if you feel that others haven't correctly evaluated what your question is actually asking.  Everything you've said since your question was closed has only confirmed that it answers your question however.  You've only ever clarified that your question is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: Ok I've made an effort to clarify. What is the best way of doing this? I mean, editing the question, adding what I've added seems cumbersome.  I would  prefer if there was a dialog box that allowed me to converse with the council of 12. Submit my reasoning and if they agreed, then put it as part of a refined post. I guess you are trying to reduce the number of dialog the moderators have to deal with.

Comment: @D-Klotz Your clarifications only confirm that the duplicates answer your question.  You've made it clear that you want to know what the appropriate way to update a UI control is.  The duplicates explain this.

Comment: /sigh ok look. I looked through most of the pages there and my lack of C# experience keeps me from recognizing which one of those pages and pages clarify that a 'main' starting thread can safely (and I stress safely) update a winform compnent. Most of what is there deals with updates from background threads. I got more information from a single comment in the OP than waiding through a sea of answers that aren't directly related to my question.

Comment: @D-Klotz You saying that you can't be bothered to read the answers that explicitly and directly answer your question doesn't make your question not a duplicate.

Comment: My god man. I'm saying that I don't have the expertise to know which one of the answers actually answers the original question. I'm still not sure it is really in there. You are. Great!

Comment: Here take a wild leap Servy, give me a link to one of the answer's that actually answers the original question. Show me that you already know which one of it is.

Comment: @D-Klotz If you don't know...can't you try the answers?  You clearly realize you don't understand C#, but that doesn't prevent you from trying them and seeing how they work.  That's how you learn.  You need to invest your own time, not expect everyone to do everything for you.

Comment: @fbueckert if I told that to a developer starting out with java swing, they can very easily go down a path where they update GUI components in the "main" thread. It works. It works so well that only once in a great while will your program deadlock. Getting a few minutes of someones time that is an expert in the field to tell them "don't" do that saves them tons of frustration. However, in general for most topics, I agree with you. Not here.

Comment: @D-Klotz [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131780/1159478) you have your answer, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/1159478) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890338/1159478) you have your answer.  I'm sure there are more that answer your question, if I'd kept looking.

Comment: @D-Klotz Well, we have to make policy based on general, not specific items.  Sometimes, the process might fall apart, but I'm not so sure it applies here.  You wanted expert help; you got an expert to close it as a dupe, so you got your answer.  It just requires some effort on your part to read and understand it.  If you don't have the expertise to understand, sounds like you've got some learning ahead of you.

Comment: @Servy. Thank you. The first link, what kept me from accepting that was this part "Hence, Control.Invoke, allows you to execute a method on the control on its own thread." and here we are running up against my ignorance of C#. I wasn't sure if that meant even in Main i used that same Invoke. I think I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: That's maybe where the differencr is @D-klotz. You want an expert to look and tell you rapidly 'do this' or 'do that'. Stack is for the next poster. Not just for you. For that intent, we have duplicates. Instead of each person getting their answer, we point them to where the best answers have been posted. It does require more work on the OP's side to validate, test and check. But it helps the OP learn more that way as well. As a casual user, it can be different from what you expect for sure.

Answer (score 18):

> This gives the OP a chance to evolve the question in a way that has dialog and answer it themselves.

SO isn't a place to have a dialog.
SO is a repository of *quality* questions and answers. Duplicating content reduces the overall quality of the content.

> get rid of the duplicate system and use the tag "may have an answer here..." with a link.

That's what the duplicate system *already* is... With the restriction of no new answers being accepted on the duplicate question.

Comment: I humbly suggest you are missing my point.

Comment: Then please elaborate, @D-Klotz?

Comment: @D-Klotz This answer gives an answer to what I thought your point was, too. You may want to clarify your post if people are misunderstanding it.

Comment: Ok. For example. You misunderstand my post. Lets say you mark it as duplicate. Within moments the post is marked and closed from further answers. Yes, I can edit it, but in reality once it is marked it changes the dynamics and it is more of a challenge to progress. I also don't agree about the dialog comment. It isn't / shouldn't be a chat room but there IS some amount of dialog. A duplicate tag IMHO changes that dynamic in a negative way.

Comment: @D-Klotz: When a closed question is edited, it's automatically bumped into a review queue, where users see it and will vote to re-open if the closure was incorrect. _"changes that dynamic in a negative way."_ isn't really answerable. It's pretty vague. And in regards to dialog: No. A good question shouldn't need comments.

Comment: @D-Klotz: There are always several sides to this issue, one, the moderation side which you're addressing in your question, but don't forget the other side -- the question asker. Your question points to the important fact that initial question quality matters quite a bit, and this is all the more reason for the OP to search the site extensively for similar problems *before* asking a question.

Comment: @D-Klotz In reality, posts do get re-opened, even dupes, plenty if they were misunderstood and edited to prove so. The first edit after a post is closed puts it in the reopen queue automatically, _and_ edits put the post to the top of the "active" tab of the questions list. Editing gets more eyes on your post, meaning if you make a good, substantial edit to clarify why your post is different from the proposed duplicate, people who view it after have a chance to reopen it. If that doesn't work, you could find a chat room to ask in, and maybe even get more tips on how to clarify your post.

Comment: All very reasonable and solid answers. The amount of work that this implies tells me that people have an abundance of time, are diligent and willing to question their own first assessments.